# python references and iterators on loops

Tags: python, loops, reference, iterator

I'd run on a subtle bug on an involved python script. Basically what went wrong looks like this

```
def inc(x):
    return x+1

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

for x in [a,b]:
    print(id(x), id(a), id(b))

for x in [a,b]:
    x = inc(x)
c = inc(c)

print(a,b,c)
```

As the first for loops shows the iterator x is taking a reference to the ongoing variable. Still when we assign a value to that iterator, the pointee(referencee) variable is not changing. I really didn't expect that behavior, this is not python, isn't?
Can some one throw some light on this?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not mutable so you can't change. Even if you change nothing will happen

Comment: It's not clear sure what you consider a bug. Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

For your first loop you print id's of `x, a, b`. `x` - is a local variable, not an `a` or `b`. Though it holds reference to the same number, it is not the same instance of reference as `a` or `b`. Integers are immutable in python. When you perform something like `x = x + 1` what you do is not changing value by the reference, but changing reference to point to new value.

Also, keep in mind that in python integers from -5 to 255 are computed even before they are referenced. That's one of pythons many optimizations.

So on first iteration `x` holds a value of `a` and as it is `1` - it is already computed and they point to the same place in memory. On the second iteration `x` points to the same value as `b`. But in neither case the reference itself is the same.

If your `a, b, c` were mutable like lists or dicts you would observe a different behaviour. Probably, the one you expect.

Comment: This is not true, it happens with mutable stuff also, just try it! Take a list and you will see. This has nothing to do with integer: it happens with other variables. My original problem was with numpy arrays which are mutable.

Comment: If you reassign mutable variable - that won't happen, but if you would, say, append to a list - it would.